# FFmpeg: Combine video files with different start times

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two webm files with audio and video recordings of a video conference session. Both files only contain one side of the conversation. They are not of the same length (someone has joined before the other one), but I have the unix timestamp in milliseconds of the start time of each video file.

On a timeline they look like this:

```
webm 1:   -----------------------------------------------
webm 2:                 -----------------------------
```

or like this:

```
webm 1:   -----------------------------------------------
webm 2:                          -----------------------------
```

I would like to combine these two video files into one file so that:

1. They appear next to each other (using the hstack option), and
2. That they are mixed with taking the time stamps of the start times
   into account. The final video should then look like this:

> Target result : --------------===========================----

The beginning and the end of the new video would show a black placeholder for the video file that has no data at this time of the mixed stream.

At the moment I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1463408731413703.webm -i 1463408880317860.webm -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2  -c:v libvpx output.webm
```

This creates a video like this:

> Not good result:  =====================------------------

i.e. the conversation is out of sync.

How can I combine two video streams with different length and different start times using ffmpeg so that I will end up with "Target result" above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried cutting longer video head-start, margin two videos and pre-pending previous removed start?

Comment: @Justinas: This would work if I am targeting 1:1 conversations only. I have simplified my question, but the goal is to mix 1:n conversations, i.e. I don't have a start time stamp when the conversation starts. Two people might talk for 5 minutes and then someone else joins too.

Comment: @Justinas: at a second thought this is a nice "hack", thanks! It might even work with 1:n conversations. I still hope that there is an option that allows me to do it in one run though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This command below presents the case for 3 inputs. First input is the longest and remains on the left. The 2nd input starts at t=1 second and lasts for 3 seconds, the 3rd lasts for 2 seconds starting at t=4s. They show on the right.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "[0]pad=2*iw:ih[l];[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1/TB[1v]; [l][1v]overlay=x=W/2[a]; \
        [2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[2v]; [a][2v]overlay=x=W/2[v]; \
        [1]adelay=1000|1000[1a]; [2]adelay=4000|4000[2a]; [0][1a][2a]amix=inputs=3[a]" \
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

The `adelay` filters are for stereo input streams.

Comment: Thanks so much, Mulvya!

Comment: How would you do this for just two videos? That is quite a mess of a command and I'm trying to figure out `a`, `0/1/2`, `l`, `[0-2][a]`, and the other variables in there.

Comment: `[x]` is a filtergraph pad, where if x = 0,1,2.. those represent the `-i` inputs starting from zero. `[2:a:2]` represents the third input's third audio stream. `[2:a]` would represent the first audio stream (same as `[2:a:0]`). If you just use `[2]`, the stream is auto-selected based on type of filter i.e. `2:v:0` for a video filter, and `2:a:0` for an audio one.  The ones with letters or other alphanumeric combos, such as `[2v]` are arbitrary, and just provide a way to reference the outputs of earlier filters for further use into other filters or for mapping.

Comment: @Mulvya can you do this with `hstack` and `vstack`?

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this, if you are still waiting for an answer:

Added 60000 ms delay for second file and 120000 ms delay for third file. First file is the longest file.

```
ffmpeg -i file_1.mp3 -i file_2.mp3 -i file_3.mp3 -filter_complex
"[1]adelay=60000[file_2];[2]adelay=120000[file_3]; [0][file_2][file_3]amix=3"
output.mp3
```